# Binding to form encoded JSON in ASP.NET MVC/Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, github, asp.net-web-api

github can alert you and call your webservice when commits are pushed to a repository ([Post-Receive Hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)).  github sends the commit information as JSON but inside a form encoded parameter.  That is, the content type is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and the http request is

```
POST /my_uri HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

payload=%7B%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads...
```

I want to write the webservice that processes the new commits in ASP.NET MVC or WebAPI.  I've defined some classes to deserialize the json, but I can't get the framework to initialize my objects directly.  What I have now is

```
public string my_uri(string payload)
{
    var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var p = s.Deserialize(payload, typeof(Payload)) as Payload;
    ...
}
```

but I would want

```
public string my_uri(Payload payload)
{
    ...
}
```

I've read about ValueProviders but I didn't find a way to chain them.  I need to compose FormValueProviderFactory and JsonValueProviderFactory.  How can I get ASP to do the binding?

Answer (score 1):

First, I am a bit confused as to why they would stuff Json data in form-encoded body data. If a service in the end can understand Json(since it has to deserialize it), why not post as "application/json" itself? Is it because of CORS that they are doing this way?

That aside, you could create a custom parameter binding like below and see if it fits your needs:

**Action**:

```
public Payload Post([PayloadParamBinding]Payload payload)
```

**Custom Parameter Binding**:

```
public class PayloadParamBindingAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return new PayloadParamBinding(parameter);
    }
}

public class PayloadParamBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    HttpParameterBinding _defaultFormatterBinding;

    public PayloadParamBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor desc)
        :base(desc)
    {
        _defaultFormatterBinding = new FromBodyAttribute().GetBinding(desc);
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Content != null)
        {
            NameValueCollection nvc = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

            StringContent sc = new StringContent(nvc["payload"]);
            //set the header so that Json formatter comes into picture
            sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            actionContext.Request.Content = sc;

            //Doing like this here because we want to simulate the default behavior of when a request
            //is posted as Json and the Json formatter would have been picked up and also the model validation is done.
            //This way you are simulating the experience as of a normal "application/json" post request.
            await _defaultFormatterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(metadataProvider, actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public override bool WillReadBody
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```